# summarize results on a vector of different length of the original - Pivot table r

Tags: r, vector, sum, pivot-table

I would like to use the vector:

```
time.int<-c(1,2,3,4,5)   #vector to be use as a "guide"
```

and the database:

```
time<-c(1,1,1,1,5,5,5)
value<-c("s","s","s","t","d","d","d")
dat1<- as.data.frame(cbind(time,value))
```

to create the following vector, which I can then add to the first vector "time.int" into a second database.

```
freq<-c(4,0,0,0,3)  #wished result
```

This vector is the sum of the events that belong to each time interval, there are four 1 in "time" so the first value gets a four and so on.

Potentially I would like to generalize it so that I can decide the interval, for example saying sum in a new vector the events in "times" each 3 numbers of time.int.

EDIT for generalization

```
time.int<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
time<-c(1,1,1,2,5,5,5,6)
value<-c("s","s","s","t", "t","d","d","d")
dat1<- data.frame(time,value)
```

let's say I want it every 2 seconds (every 2 time.int)

```
freq<-c(4,0,4)  #wished result
```

or every 3

```
freq<-c(4,4)  #wished result
```

I know how to do that in excel, with a pivot table.

sorry if a duplicate I could not find a fitting question on this website, I do not even know how to ask this and where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will produce vector `freq`.

```
freq <- sapply(time.int, function(x) sum(x == time))
freq
[1] 4 0 0 0 3
```

BTW, don't use the construct `as.data.frame(cbind(.))`. Use instead

```
dat1 <- data.frame(time,value))
```

In order to generalize the code above to segments of `time.int` of any length, I believe the following function will do it. Note that since you've changed the data the output for `n == 1` is not the same as above.

```
fun <- function(x, y, n){
    inx <- lapply(seq_len(length(x) %/% n), function(m) seq_len(n) + n*(m - 1))
    sapply(inx, function(i) sum(y %in% x[i]))
}

freq1 <- fun(time.int, time, 1)
freq1
[1] 3 1 0 0 3 1

freq2 <- fun(time.int, time, 2)
freq2
[1] 4 0 4

freq3 <- fun(time.int, time, 3)
freq3
[1] 4 4
```

Comment: Brilliant! And if I would like to generalize? To be able to say sum in a new vector the events in "times" each 3 numbers of time.int instead of 1 by 1?

Comment: @havefun Maybe you could do it with a nested `sapply`, but you would need to edit your question and say what the expected output would be.

Comment: I now edited my question, ideally I would like to choose a parameter at the beginning and use that to divide the vector.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `table` function to count the event number and use `merge` to create a data frame summarizing the information. `event_dat` is the final output.

```
# Create example data 
time.int <- c(1,2,3,4,5)   
time <- c(1,1,1,1,5,5,5)

# Count the event using table and convert to a data frame
event <- as.data.frame(table(time))

# Convert the time.int to a data frame
time_dat <- data.frame(time = time.int) 

# Merge the data 
event_dat <- merge(time_dat, event, by = "time", all = TRUE)

# Replace NA with 0
event_dat[is.na(event_dat)] <- 0

# See the result
event_dat
  time Freq
1    1    4
2    2    0
3    3    0
4    4    0
5    5    3
```